# Rendering GetStream React Feed into PHP

Tags: php, reactjs

Nice to finally be part of the community! I am currently building a web app for fun and I've been playing around with the GetStream feed using Php. I'm very new at Jquery and I've just been trying to render the react component into a certain div but it doesn't seem to be working. It is showing a blank page.

Regards,

Asuka

Comment: Please provide more context. You can post something like code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

@triaton

My .php

```
            <div id="content">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="Calender">
             
          </div>
                <div class="hours-worked"></div>
                <div class="booked-hotels"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="notification-bar">
        <script type ="text/babel" src="notification.js"></script>
        </div>
```

And this is my JS file;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StreamApp, StatusUpdateForm, FlatFeed } from 'react-activity-feed';
import 'react-activity-feed/dist/index.es.css';
export default class App extends Component {
   render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '600px', margin: '0 auto' }}>
        <StreamApp
          apiKey="<YOUR_API_KEY>"
          appId="<YOUR_APP_ID>"
          token="<A_TOKEN_FOR_THE_CURRENT_USER>"
        >
          <StatusUpdateForm />
          <FlatFeed feedGroup="user" notify />
        </StreamApp>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('notification-bar'));
```